# Is it legitimate for a database-driven website to read the DB once (at SessionStart)?

Tags: database

I'm working on a webapp that is supposed to be "database-driven".  Now, the stuff we do is a bit evolved *(a little configurator)* and I hesitate to re-read the DB on every callback, because I fear data might become inconsistent (several linked tables are involved) and possibly a lot of checking would have to be added to avoid that.

So my idea was to read all required data when a user session starts and work with that. The data in general is rather static, new configurations created in a session will be stored and have no impact on other sessions. However, a coworker involved with testing now claimed that this was "not database-driven", as data was cached (for the duration of a session).

My understanding was very naive - I had assumed "database-driven" to mean "based on data held in a database" (as opposed to "data held in .xml-files"). But does the general understanding of the term also imply "**no caching**"?

Comment: Do not reason about a design because somone mentioned it should be "insert-your-favorite-buzzword-here"-driven.  Instead, ask if your design matches your **actual requirements**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand "database-driven" to mean that the normal, ongoing operations of the application will be directed based on the state of data at the time of (or very near the time of) the operation. Meaning, as time elapses, the data will change, which will in turn affect the application's state.

If the application only contacts a database once, but then operates disconnected for the rest of its normal lifetime, then I would not consider that "database-driven".

In the scenario you describe, the connection to the database is incidental, as the application would operate the same even if it got its initial data from a text file, or really any other initialization process. In other words, the "database" part is there, but not the "driven" part.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers are helpful, but your emphasis on the "driven" part was helpful and probably closer to what my coworker thought. (Now we're having a debate on whether that requirement makes sense for this app - because whatever one user does has no impact on other users...)

Answer (score 4):

I think of it as data-driven vs. code driven. For example you have an application which is available in different countries, and your code looks like this

```
if (country == "Germany") {
    // do this
}
else if (country == "France") {
    // do that
}
```

then you are not data-driven. Any change requires a code change.

On the other hand, if the list of supported countries, their currencies, sales tax rates etc. are loaded from a database, you are data-driven. Adding a country is not a code change.

In my mind, it's completely irrelevant how the data is stored or what caching strategy is used. Maybe your coworker wants to discuss the caching strategy?